# How to prepare shirataki noodles to more closely resemble classic pasta?

Tags: pasta, noodles, japanese-cuisine

I've tried [shirataki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shirataki_noodles) in spaghetti with meat sauce but the noodles' texture and flavor didn't fit with the sauce very well. Perhaps there's a way to make it work that I'm not aware of?

I'd like to figure out how to prep and use shirataki noodles so that they take on a texture of classic pasta which would open many culinary possibilities. Any hints and ideas?

Comment: I'm sorry but right now this question is basically a recipe request, which is off topic here.  However, if you wanted to ask about pairings for these noodles or why the spaghetti sauce didn't work, we could probably help you out there.  If you are looking for the basic techniques how to properly prepare them, I'm sure that somebody has an answer there too.

Comment: @sarge: Sure, i'll redo the question.

Comment: Thank you ma'am.  Hopefully, someone will be along shortly to answer this for you :)

Comment: Why not use regular pasta? If the flavor and texture don't work, and shirataki have almost no food value anyway (apart from fiber), it hardly seems worth the effort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a bunch of Googling and reading I found that there are several ways to improve the noodles:

- Rinse and drain them very, very well
- Boil them for an extended amount of time to reduce the crunch
- Dry them out in a pan (they'll shrivel a bit) before adding them to recipes where they either remain crunchy (in dryer dishes) or absorb sauce and flavor (saucier dishes)

Here are some my sources:

- [Shrimp Scampi](http://www.miraclenoodle.com/phpBB2/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=681&sid=c21dd6c3af11d293640f7ad322c3238b)
- [List with many recipes](http://www.miraclenoodle.com/phpBB2/viewforum.php?f=2&sid=a64f9ec33c6040e3300e0652039d7974)
- [Various suggestions](http://www.lowcarbfriends.com/bbs/atkins-nutritional-approach/671286-finally-how-fix-tasty-shirataki-noodles.html)